# I'm having trouble running a python script and then continuing with my bash script

Tags: command-line, python, ssh, iphone, tunnel

I am using tcprelay.py from [usbmuxd](http://marcansoft.com/blog/iphonelinux/usbmuxd/) to forward local port 2222 to remote port 22 so that I can SSH into my iPhone over USB.
If I run

```
python ~/Downloads/usbmuxd-1.0.8/python-client/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222
```

It successfully forwards the port, and in another terminal window, I can run

```
ssh -l root -p 2222 127.0.0.1
```

and successfully use SSH over USB. However, I am trying to combine this into one command, and

```
python ~/Downloads/usbmuxd-1.0.8/python-client/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222
ssh -l root -p 2222 127.0.0.1
```

does not work. After running the python command, I cannot run any other commands in that window. How would I go about putting these two commands together?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the first command run in the background and start the second one after the first has been initiated. I'm sure there is a more elegant way (of sorts) but this should do the trick.

```
python ~/Downloads/usbmuxd-1.0.8/python-client/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222 &
ssh -l root -p 2222 127.0.0.1
```

The ampersand at the end tells bash to run the python command in the background.

In the event you need to run the script a second time you might need to find the running python command and kill it, before you can run it a second time. Else it will complain that the port is already blocked.

Answer (score 2):

An adaptation of MadMike's answer, you can use the following commands:

```
python ~/Downloads/usbmuxd-1.0.8/python-client/tcprelay.py -t 22:2222 &

while ! (: < /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/2222) 2>/dev/null; do
    sleep 1
done

ssh -l root -p 2222 127.0.0.1
```

This will execute the python program in the background, then wait (checking once a second) until internal port 2222 is open. It will then run the `ssh` program.

[Source for checking if a port is open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875805/2734389)